# QGIS GDAL Vectorinformation: Can only extract one layer of the geopackage while I want all

Tags: qgis, gdal

Currently I am trying to extract vector information with the GDAL Vectorinformation tool on a geopackage. The problem is I only get one layer extracted out of the geopackage while I want the information of all the layers in the geopackage. Is this a limitation of the tool?

Comment: are you talking about 'ogrinfo' ?

Comment: I am talking about the GDAL tool you get in your QGIS process box: if that is what you mean with ogrinfo I guess yes then.

Comment: It is not possible, since QGIS associated one QgsVectorLayer object to each layer in your geopackage. I believe you can do it with the command line interface (ogrinfo), but you need to specify your layer name with opt '-nomd' , and you will need a loop to run ogrinfo for each GPKG component. So it will be the same if you do it manually for each layer with the GUI.

Comment: Okay how do I do that to make it loop?

Comment: I can help you with bash if you're working with linux or macos.. but for windows it may be more difficult